# 404 Error on firebase deploy after adding target

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I added target to firebase project because there is going to be subdomains. I've done this before, but never encountered this error. So I created the project in the firebase console. Then I opened the project in my terminal.

```
firebase init
... chose existing project // Website
firebase deploy // website is now live at firebase domain
```

Then I added a target...

```
firebase target:apply hosting website Website
```

Now I went to my firebase.json file and it looks like this

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "website" // this causes Error: 404, Requested entity was not found
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error after I add that target and run firebase deploy in the terminal. Maybe I need to add the target to my firebase.rc as well?